# how to reload NSFetchedResultsController with new filter Predicates in background thread?

Tags: swift, core-data, uisearchbar, grand-central-dispatch, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i have UISearchBar and try to append some filters in my base, but when i trying to reload my NSFetchedResultsController with new Predicates sometimes reloading contains about 10 seconds (for one Predicate) and at other time only 2 seconds for this one Predicate. All attributes in Core Data which used in Predicates are indexed.
Why this happend and how to fix this?

fetchResultController code

```
lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)
    return appDelegate!.managedObjectContext
}()

lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<CardsBaseClass> = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<CardsBaseClass>(entityName: "CardsBase")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "cardName", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 50
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

UISearchBar method

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    block?.cancel()
    var predicateArray = predicateArrayClass.arrayOfPredicates
    block = DispatchWorkItem {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(self.searchPredicateName) contains[c] %@", searchText)
        predicateArray.append(predicate)
        self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicateArray)
        print(self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate)
        self.connectFetchedRequest()
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: block!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the main thread Core Data managed object context on a background thread.

When using background threads in Core Data, it is better to use the framework itself rather than GDC or the `DispatchQueue` APIs. Core Data provides block APIs and the concept of parent and child contexts. I think in your code you are violating the main principle of these APIs: always run a different context on its own thread, and vice versa: don't run any context on more than one thread.

I recommend to create a child context and use `performBlock` to do the search.

Comment: i added the MOC child but its don't help, write new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712137/filtering-nsfetchedresultcontroller-via-searchbar-without-loading-base-pauses